# query related to installing androidapp 2times

Tags: android-studio, android-query

I developed an application , which consist of 2 working modes , Initially 2 modes are disabled .

And iam enabling those 2 modes during app working condition(i.e by applying each checkbox to each mode).

Now i have a requirement that needs 2 apps each consist of each mode from above mentioned 2 modes.

How can i install the same app 2 times by enabling each mode in each app

what are the changes i need to do in manifest file (i.e changing name or label name , etc..) to  install the same app with 2 different names in the same mobile.

iam expecting a detailed view on this particular problem.